# How can i create a parse query for android that will get every comment that a certain person has made?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Hello i am making an app where barbers can submit their schedules(times) and then if a client clicks their name the client will be shown all of the times that that certain barber has submitted. Lets say that the barbers name is stored in the string "barberName" and that the barber names are stored in the "name" column and in the "User" class and so are the times which are stored in the "times" column. How would i get all the times that the barber "Jonathan"(This name is an Example) has made. Please answer the code that i would need to write, i have already made the query but it only gets the times that the newest barber has inputted. A couple of days ago the code was working but now it is not. This is my code...

```
  final String name =  getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Info");
  query.whereEqualTo("user", name);
  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
     @Override
     public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
          if (e == null){
              ArrayList<String> barbers = new ArrayList<String>();

              for (ParseObject object : objects){

                barbers.add(String.valueOf(object.get("times")));

              }

            ArrayAdapter arrayAdaptar = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (Barbers.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, barbers);

            list.setAdapter(arrayAdaptar);



        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities here: Is "user" just a name? That is likely a bad solution, since multiple users could have the same name. I'd instead store an objectId of the User, or a pointer to the user. That'll make these more uniquely identifiable.

Queries by default only have a limit of 100 items, so it'll only fetch the first 100 results. Perhaps you are running into a limit issue?

Have you double checked that you are in fact inputting the name you expect to be? Maybe your issue is that you aren't updating it properly. It sounds like maybe you're setting that value when your list is fetched, so the last one is the one that the name gets set to. THen, when you tap one, you're using that instead of the name on the Info object you are selecting.